# Why is GREP outputting BINARY FILES rather than a SINGLE FILE named “0.jpg”?

Tags: grep

I love BASH but am struggling with GREP.

**My goal is simple: GREP my Desktop files for “0.jpg”.**

**MY BASH CODE:**

```
$ pwd
/Users/jennalusche/Desktop
$ grep "0" *.jpg
```

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

```
0.jpg
```

**ACTUAL RESULT:**

```
Binary file IMG_2125.jpg matches
Binary file the-letter-just-j-bw-vectorized-v2.jpg matches
```

**OPERATING SYSTEM**

Mac OS X Yosemite

**MY QUESTION**

Why is GREP “0” *.jpg showing BINARY FILES rather than a SINGLE FILE named “0.jpg”?

**MY DEBUGGING RATIONALE**

I’m assuming the reason these files are showing up is due to the fact that they are both “Binary.”
“Binary File” = the file is coded in 0’s & 1’s. Thus, both files showing up must translate as 0’s, while all the other files in my PWD translate as 1’s.

**MY OBVIOUS QUESTION —**

Why isn’t 0.jpg the output?

**RATIONALE CHECK**

I’m assuming both the output files, in binary terms, are 0’s and all other files in the PWD are 1’s. Is this assumption correct?

**GOING DOWN THE RABBIT HOLE —**

Why are the resulting files 0’s? I didn’t code these files in any special way on purpose.
Are the files that didn’t show up from my GREP search coded as 1’s? If so, why?

**TUMBLING DOWN DEEPER RABBIT HOLE —**
**GREP. SED. AWK. LS. CAT. ECHO. FIND.**

Obviously there is a lot of overlap in the functionality of each of these utilities.

What’s your favorite combination, in terms of usage?

Comment: It is unclear what it is you actually want to do. You say that your expected output is `0.jpg`, i.e. a _filename_, but `grep` looks _inside_ files for lines that match patterns. Could you please clarify whether you are looking for filenames or if you are trying to match the content of files?

Comment: From `grep` manual: "grep searches for PATTERN in each FILE.". Please reconsider your question and avoid introducing discussions next time.

Comment: `grep` is writing out that a 0 was found in a binary file. its a warning... supposed to be a "feature." maybe it is ... the `grep` you use on a system containing binary files is not the `grep` originally designed to work on a system devoid of binary files...

Comment: @Kusalananda You just answered my question. I'm missing the option to limit searches to titles only Thanks for the rapid expert advice!

Comment: @ploth I apologize for bad form. I'm new to posting to this forum, & I thought discussions were somewhat encouraged. Where would you recommend posting discussions? Thanks!

Comment: @mikeserv Would you mind elaborating on what a "warning" is &/or point me to a site where I can learn more? Thanks! I really appreciate the advice.

Comment: I would suggest in the future researching and studying more the subject and writing shorter questions.

Comment: jlusche:   the "warning" is extra information about the `grep` matches. `grep` is supposed to read text files... once upon a time all files were supposed to be text files...

Answer (score 2):

The `grep` utility *looks inside files* for lines matching regular expressions.

What you (seem to) want to do is to list all files in the current directory that contain a `0` (zero) in their filenames and that has a filename suffix of `.jpg`.  To do this, you would use something like

```
ls -l ./*0*.jpg
```

or indeed just

```
echo ./*0*.jpg
```

The first part of the pattern, `*0*`, would match any string that contains a zero, while the last part of the pattern, `.jpg`, will limit the resulting filenames to those that end with that suffix.  The `./` means "in this directory" and is only really needed if you have filenames beginning with `-` (dash) (these would potentially otherwise be misinterpreted as command line options)¹.

The expansion of this pattern is done by the shell before calling `ls`, so `ls` would get the expanded list of filenames that match the pattern and would list these.

Note that filename globbing patterns are not regular expressions (only *similar* to them).  `grep`, on the other hand, takes one or several regular expressions and searches for them in the contents of files.

---

Answering a question found [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466188/why-is-grep-outputting-binary-files-rather-than-a-single-file-named-0-jpg/466191#comment848891_466188):  A "warning" is a form of non-fatal *diagnostic* output.  The other type is an "error", which is usually fatal (i.e. the program is unable to continue as usual and terminates after outputting the error message).

Diagnostic messages are usually not considered part of the standard output that a command produces during normal operation and is usually produced on a special "output stream" (on the so called "standard error stream" as opposed to on the "standard output stream") so that it may be inspected separately, or discarded, and so that it does not interfere with the ordinary output of the command.

In this case though, `grep` is unable to actually *show* the data that matched the pattern since the file is binary and the data very likely is unprintable, so instead it notifies you that there was a match in the file through the message `Binary file IMG_2125.jpg matches` instead (this is not actually a diagnostic warning message as [mikeserv suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/52934/mikeserv)).

---

<sup>¹ Note that if some filenames contain backslash characters, some `echo` implementations would interpret the `\n`, `\b`... as escape sequences to expand.</sup>